# Identifying Web elements that have no obvious identifier

Tags: selenium, timeout, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I have written a Webdriver test that when ran, sometimes completes and sometimes doesn't.

I can't see why, my guess is that the way I verify that the page has loaded is not robust.

I verify that the website is in the correct place by waiting for a element "id/name/css or text on page, but there some elements that I can find:

```html
<a href="javascript:doaction('1');">
<img src="images/english/go.gif" border="0" width="39" height="24"></a>

<a href="javascript:doaction('2');">
<img src="images/english/go.gif" border="0" width="39" height="24"></a>

<a href="javascript:doaction('3');">
<img src="images/english/go.gif" border="0" width="39" height="24"></a>
```

Does anyone no of an effective way find these elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the element by its attributes, like href and src.

```java
By link = By.cssSelector("a[href=\"javascript:doaction('1');\"]"); // The quotes are escaped out because of the single quotes in the href.  Normally I would just do like I did with src and use single quotes around the href
By src = By.cssSelector("img[src='images/english/go.gif']");

WebElement linkElement = driver.findElement(link);
linkElement.click();

WebElement srcElement = driver.findElement(src);
srcElement.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a method from `By` that is `linkText`, that find's the elements according to it's href="" property.

i.e. (assuming driver is already started).

```java
By doActionOneAnchor = By.linkText("javascript:doaction('1')");
WebElement doActionOne = driver.findElement(doActionOne);
```

That's the WebElement you will be able to use it. If for some reason you need to act upon the images itself you can always do:

```java
WebElement imgDoActionOne = doActionOne.findElement(By.tagName("img"));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how do you find the Image element by its "src"?

Comment: I am not sure the 1st part of your example is correct surely linkText refers to the interal text of the tag like this: `<a class="rightmenuanchor" href="javascript:jumptosection('TEAM');">Team</a>`